# file transfer from Tiger (10.4.11) to Mountain Lion (10.8)

Tags: macos, file-transfer, file

Will Migration Assistant let me transfer my files from my old Mac running Tiger 10.4.11 to Mountain Lion?  I've read that it does not support moving files from 10.4 to Mountain Lion and didn't know if the .11 on my version made a difference as to it working or not.

Also my old Mac only has USB 2 and firewire, new Mac USB3 and Thunderbolt.  So I don't know how I would make the connection.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have specific files you are transferring? Ie, your home account? If you put the old Mac into TARGET mode, you can use the ThunderBolt->FW800 adapter and a FW800->FW400 cable to mount your old Mac like an external drive and copy whatever you need over. The migration assistant may be able to read from the drive to pull data as well.

Answer (score 1):

Mountain Lion's Migration Assistant supports direct migration from 10.4.11 only on FireWire. Newer OS than Tiger allow Network Migration in addition to FireWire mode.

See http://support.apple.com/kb/HT4889 for details.